# PHP generated JSON to Javascript - two scripts with hardcoded arrays works and the other mysql generated arrays not work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

PHP generated array then json_encode as output Javascript.  I have two php script,

the one with hard coded array works and the other one with mysql generated array does not work.  Your help in making the mysql one work will be highly appreciated.

PHP that works, the JSON passed to javascript which displays JSON object correctly.

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        "first_name" => "Darian",
        "last_name" => "Brown",
        "age" => "28",
        "email" => "darianbr@example.com"
    ),
    array(
        "first_name" => "John",
        "last_name" => "Doe",
        "age" => "47",
        "email" => "john_doe@example.com"
    )
);


echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

---

php with mysql generated array NOT work, javascript cannot display the json object.

```
$result_event = mysqli_query($bd, $qry);

$json = array();

while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_event)) {
    $json[] = array("first_name" => $r['first_name'], "last_name" => $r['last_name'], "age" => $r['age'], "email" => $r['email']);

}

echo json_encode($json);
mysqli_close($bd);
```

---

Here's the Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
                $.getJSON('json_encoded_array.php', function(data) { 
                //$.getJSON('getEventJSON.php', function (data) {
                    /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.first_name + ' ' + val.last_name + ' ' + val.email + ' ' + val.age + '</li>'); 
                        //$('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.active + ' ' + val.event_id + '</li>');
                });
            });
       });
    </script>
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? What's actually being output?

Comment: Not working means no output, here's the output of the working php script as two "li":   Darian Brown darianbr@example.com 28
John Doe john_doe@example.com 47

Comment: What's the output of `json_encoded_array.php`?

Comment: @Alexander working output (two "li" under "ul"):                   Darian Brown darianbr@example.com 28                            John Doe john_doe@example.com 47

Comment: I don't follow. Can you add the plain JSON text that `echo json_encode($json);` is producing to the question?

Comment: i ran both script in the browser, both output the same  json structure

Comment: @makarthur - in that case, if they really are identical (which doesn't seem possible, since you get a different output from what you claim are identical inputs) just adding either one to your question would be to your benefit. None of the output you've shown yet is valid JSON. It would looks something like: `[{"first_name":"Darian","last_name":"Brown","age":"28","email":"darianbr@example.com"},{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","age":"47","email":"john_doe@example.com"}]`

Comment: run json_encoded_array.php at browser, output=[{"first_name":"Darian","last_name":"Brown","age":"28","email":"darianbr@example.com"},{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","age":"47","email":"john_doe@example.com"}]

Comment: run (getEventJSON.php (mysql generated array) at browser, output=[{"active":"1","event_id":"9"},{"active":"1","event_id":"5"},{"active":"1","event_id":"3"},{"active":"1","event_id":"6"},{"active":"0","event_id":"8"},{"active":"0","event_id":"10"},{"active":"0","event_id":"4"},{"active":"0","event_id":"7"},{"active":"0","event_id":"2"},{"active":"0","event_id":"1"}]

Comment: Will there be anything wrong with the Javascript part?  or something doing with mysql output funny characters?

Comment: @makarthur - sorry, didn't realize you'd replied (use an @ before someone's username to ensure SO notifies them). I can't see anything untoward with the output you've shown - nor any special characters. I'm not conversant with jQuery, so can't help you there either. :( Sorry!

Comment: @enhzflep Found that netbean generated license header clog up the json output, i.e. making it not in json format.  As I cannot resolve I make up another test case, see the below question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902181/php-script-json-encode-mysql-request-cannot-pass-through-to-getjson

Comment: @makarthur - Ahhhhhh! That'd do it. Glad you appear to have solved your problem. Reminds me of using Dreamweaver nearly a decade ago - it too would add things to the code.