# PHP script json_encode mysql request cannot pass through to getJSON()

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, getjson

Really note help from guru on the below mystery.

I used `getJSON()` in my html.

Only hardcoded array can be json_encode (i.e. by setting `$DEBUG = true`:) and pass to javascript and subsequently browser display the result.  But fail when generate the text from mysql (by setting `$DEBUG = false`).

I am scratching my head to get mysql generated dynamic array to work?  I can run both scenario in the browser with JSON formated text output in the browser, i.e http://www.example.com/phpTWLLT/json_encoded_array.php.

If `$DEBUG` is set `true`,

output from localhost/phpTWLLT/json_encode_array.php

```
[{"active":"0","first_name":"Darian","last_name":"Brown","age":"28","email":"darianbr@example.com"},{"active":"1","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","age":"47","email":"john_doe@example.com"}]
```

the list displayed in browser.
0
1

If `$DEBUG` is set `false`,

output from localhost/phpTWLLT/json_encode_array.php

```
[{"active":"1"},{"active":"1"}]
```

The browser display is blank.

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <!--
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'>    </script>
        -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>    
    <body>

    <!-- this UL will be populated with the data from the php array -->
    <ul></ul>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            /* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
            //$.getJSON('json_encoded_array.php', function(data) { 
            $.getJSON('json_encoded_array.php', function (data) {
                /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */

                 $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                 $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.active  + '</li>');
                 });

            });
        });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

PHP script: json_encoded_array.php

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */



/* set out document type to text/javascript instead of text/html */


$DEBUG = true;

if ($DEBUG) {
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
    $arr = array(
        array(
            "active" => "0",
            "first_name" => "Darian",
            "last_name" => "Brown",
            "age" => "28",
            "email" => "darianbr@example.com"
        ),
        array(
            "active" => "1",
            "first_name" => "John",
            "last_name" => "Doe",
            "age" => "47",
            "email" => "john_doe@example.com"
        ) 
    );
} else {
    require_once('connection.php');
// $m_id= 8 has many enrolled course and 11 got exactly one course enrolled. 
    $m_id = 8;
    $p_id = 1;

    $qry1 = "SELECT distinct event.active as active, subject.code as 'courseCode', subject.name as     'courseName', event.event_desc as 'eventDesc' FROM applicant, event, subject, part where applicant.applicant_id = $m_id and applicant.event_id = event.id and event.subject_id=subject.id and part.id = subject.owner_id and part.id = $p_id order by event.active DESC, event.from_month DESC ";
    mysqli_set_charset($bd, 'utf-8');
    $result = mysqli_query($bd, $qry1);

    $arr = array();
    $i = 0;
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ( $rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)  ) {
             $colhead = "active";
            $str = $rs['active'];

            $arr[$i] = array($colhead => $str);
            $i++;

                // just generate two record for testing
                if ($i === 2)
                break;

        }
    } 
}
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a header to output it as `json` in PHP script: json_encoded_array.php

```
 header("Content-type: application/json");
```

By default PHP will return `text/html` which is not a valid JSON for `$.getJSON()`

The MIME media type for JSON text is application/json. The default encoding is UTF-8. (Source: [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)).

Comment: He could even use `$.ajax` setting `dataType: 'JSON'`. Wouldn't even have to mind setting header on PHP, just returning a JSON string.

Comment: Ya that can be done, but its good practice to return valid header json with `header("Content-type: application/json");`

Comment: @Saqueib added the header, but no change to browser output

Comment: @makarthur: You need to set the header outside the `if` condition to work on both cases. And you are just passing "active" trough your secound condition, what do you want it to return? The same as the first?

Comment: @makarthur if you can share the console screenshot it will be great help

Comment: @Saquieb I do not have sufficient reputation to post image. please go to http://www.arthurmak.hk/debugTrue.jpg and http://www.arthurmak.hk/debugFalse.jpg

Comment: @makarthur see this how to inspect [ajax in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939172/in-chrome-how-can-i-see-what-ajax-requests-are-being-made) and post the screenshot

Comment: @Saqueib upload the jpg at http://www.arthurmak.hk/debugFalse1.jpg  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Saqueib upload more jpg at http://www.arthurmak.hk/debugFalse1.jpg  http://www.arthurmak.hk/debugFalse2.jpg  http://www.arthurmak.hk/debugFalse3.jpg  http://www.arthurmak.hk/debugFalse4.jpg  http://www.arthurmak.hk/debugFalse5.jpg    Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Saqueib upload more jpg at http://www.arthurmak.hk/debugTrue1.jpg   http://www.arthurmak.hk/debugTrue2.jpg   http://www.arthurmak.hk/debugTrue3.jpg   http://www.arthurmak.hk/debugTrue4.jpg    Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Saqueib looking at debugFalse3 and debugFalse4  compared to debugTrue2 and debugTrue3, the differnce is the License comments

Comment: @makarthur: It seems that you set the header on **true** condition, but not on **false**. Try to set it outside the `if` condition.

Comment: @Sqqueib Got it work.  After removing the default license header which blocked the javascript from recognizing JSON format. Have a look at the output  http://www.arthurmak.hk/debugFalseWorking.jpg

Answer (score 1):

`$.each` takes a javascript array or object to loop through `not a json string` first you need to parse your json string using

`jQuery.parseJSON()`

so your code will look like this

```
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.active  + '</li>');
    });
```

Comment: tried the above code, neither $DEBUG=true nor $DEBUG=false produce output.

Comment: tried the above code, neither $DEBUG=true nor $DEBUG=false produce output. and output error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o (22:06:01:876 | error, javascript)
  at testGetJson.html:1
>

Answer (score 1):

Found that default License Header from Netbeans (which is automatically generated) prevented Javascript from recognizing the JSON structure.

After removing the default License Header by modifying the default License Header to blank.  The output from PHP script only contains the JSON structure.  The browser display correctly.

Please compare the two debug output below (Cannot post images)
debugFalse4.jpg: http://www.arthurmak.hk/debugFalse4.jpg
debugFalseWrking.jpg: http://www.arthurmak.hk/debugFalseWorking.jpg

Thanks a lot to Saquieb showing how to obtain the debug information!!!